# How to set an objects rotation to follow a line in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have 2 vectors that form a line and I want to place the object at one of the vectors, with a rotation that follows this angle.

I have tried using most of the functions in unity that I can find but cannot get it right at all.

Comment: What do you mean by forming a line with two vectors? One vector forms a line by itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use [`Quaternion.LookRotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.LookRotation.html) to compute a rotation. Just give it a vector for the vector between the two points, and a "up-direction", probably `Vector3.up`.

```
var rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(p1 - p2, Vector3.up);
```

or - since `Vector3.up` is the default value anyway

```
var rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(p1 - p2);
```

Comment: Note that `LookAt` will not work like that! Your code is more the usage of `Quaternion.LookRotation` using a certain direction (= vector `p2-p1` .. pointing from `p1` towards `p2`). `Transform.LookAt` on the other hand will always use your current `transform.position` and as parameter rather expects a target **position** to look at, **not a direction**! So here it would rather be `transform.LookAt(transform.position + p2 - p1);`

Comment: @derHugo thanks, I'm not that familiar with unity, and I was a bit sloppy with reading the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

in the name of God. The following command will solve your problem.

```cs
transform.position = v1;
transform.forward = (v2 - v1).normalized;
```

Comment: Not sure why god is involved

Comment: @DavidTilman if my solution helps you please tick and upvote then I'll say a good reason that why god is involved.

Comment: I didn’t use that

Comment: @DavidTilman don't care any way.